# Set vaadin theme by hostname

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to set the theme of a vaadin app depending on the hostname which is used to access the app e.g. app.company.de uses "valo", app.company.org uses "org-theme".
If I set the UI programmatic in the UI class, I get a "flicker" because the theme from `@Theme` is used first.
I also tried to modify the bootstrap page by adding a `BootstrapListener` like this:

```
            @Override
            public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {
                Document doc = response.getDocument();
                for (Element script : doc.getElementsByTag("script")) {
                    if (script.html().contains("\"theme\": \"valo\"")) {
                        String old = script.html();
                        String newHtml = old.replace("valo", THEME_NAME);
                        script.html(newHtml);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But this leads to some escaping problems, which one might solve, but still I don't feel good by changing the bootstrap js a such a hacky way.

Is there a way to hook into where the bootstrap js is created?

Comment: I don't know if it would be an elegant solution, but if you're using an apache http server you could add a rewrite rule for /VAADIN/themes/valo/* to /VAADIN/themes/org-theme/* based on the request header

Comment: When did you set the theme? In `init` method of UI class?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich if you set it in `init` you get the flicker effect, at least for me it did with 7.7.3. What was weird, is that if I tried setting it in the constructor, it had no effect... I got a `reindeer` look&feel, and I didn't find any reference about this behaviour, I'm wondering whether this is the desired behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a custom `UIProvider` that overrides **getTheme** method?

`public String getTheme(UICreateEvent event) {...}`

Another solution could be extendinf `VaadinServletService` and override **getConfiguredTheme**.

`public String getConfiguredTheme(VaadinRequest request) {...}`

Comment: Extending the UIProvider works. Do you know how to get to the requestURL from the `UICreateEvent` without casting to `HttpServletRequestWrapper` ?

Comment: At least a cast must be done. But you can avoid casting to HttpServletRequestWrapper in this way

`((VaadinServletRequest)uiCreateEvent.getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest()`